React Native Bluetooth Thermal Printer Package for Image Printing
I am developing a POS application using React Native and need to print both text and images using a Bluetooth thermal printer. I have already integrated basic text printing functionality, but I am now facing challenges when trying to print images (like logos or product images) to the thermal printer over Bluetooth.
Could anyone recommend a React Native package that supports image printing for Bluetooth thermal printers? It would be great if the package supports commonly used models (like GoojPRT.) and provides functionality for scaling or adjusting the image size to fit the paper width.
If you have any advice or sample code, I would really appreciate it!
Thanks in advance!
